# how to deploy jenkins on the jetty correctly?

Tags: java, jenkins, jetty

I'm trying to deploy jenkins on the jetty application server as follows:

**Unpack the distribution**

[~]$ unzip jetty-distribution-9.3.2.v20150730 
[~]$ cd jetty-distribution-9.3.2.v20150730

**Copy your war into place**

[jetty-distribution-9.3.2.v20150730]$ cp ~/Projects/mywebapp.war webapps/

**Run Jetty**

[jetty-distribution-9.3.2.v20150730]$ java -jar start.jar

My version of java is:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

I am getting the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/start/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Which version of the jetty I use with version 7 of java?

Answer (score 3):

Java 7 is now EOL (End of Life) with Oracle.

Would **highly** recommend you use Java 8 from here on out.

Jenkins runs fine on Java 8 and Jetty 9.3.2 (the Jetty project themselves do this).

Comment: Hello Joakim Erdfelt, at the moment I can not migrate to java 8. You would know tell me which version of Jetty supports java 7? Thanks!

Comment: @ricardoramos Jetty 9.2.13.v20150730 - here is the [link](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/)

Comment: @Dmitry would still recommend using Java 8, even with Jetty 9.2.x series.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I do agree it's better to use Java 8 at this point of time, but original author of the question has some legacy stuff I guess, which prevents him акщь using the latest version

Answer (score 2):

Jetty 9.3.x runs only with Java 1.8.
Jetty 9.0.x - 9.2.x runs with Java 1.7, so download latest stable 9.2.13.v20150730.