# How to deploy Jenkins in Jetty server correctly?

Tags: java, deployment, jenkins, jetty, war

After installing the jetty on ubuntu I deployed the jenkins as root on the jetty as follows:

```
/opt/jetty/webapps$ ls
jenkins-1.622.war  jenkins.xml  spdy.war
service jetty restart
```

I created the [jenkins.xml](http://pietervogelaar.nl/ubuntu-12-04-install-jenkins-1-4-with-jetty-9) file:

```
nano /opt/jetty/webapps/jenkins.xml
```

I copied and pasted the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<!-- ==================================================================
Configure and deploy the jenkins web application in $(jetty.home)/webapps/jenkins

Note. If this file did not exist or used a context path other that /jenkins
then the default configuration of jetty.xml would discover the jenkins
webapplication with a WebAppDeployer.  By specifying a context in this
directory, additional configuration may be specified and hot deployments
detected.
===================================================================== -->

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">


  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!-- Required minimal context configuration :                        -->
  <!--  + contextPath                                                  -->
  <!--  + war OR resourceBase                                          -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <Set name="contextPath">/jenkins</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/jenkins.war</Set>

  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <!-- Optional context configuration                                  -->
  <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
  <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>
  <Set name="copyWebDir">false</Set>
  <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
  <!--<Set name="overrideDescriptor"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/jenkins.d/override-web.xml</Set>-->

  <Get name="securityHandler">
    <Set name="loginService">
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
        <Set name="name">Jenkins Realm</Set>
        <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
            <!-- To enable reload of realm when properties change, uncomment the following lines -->
            <!-- changing refreshInterval (in seconds) as desired                                -->
            <!--
           <Set name="refreshInterval">5</Set>
           <Call name="start"></Call>
           -->
      </New>
    </Set>
    <Set name="authenticator">
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator">
        <Set name="alwaysSaveUri">true</Set>
      </New>
    </Set>
    <Set name="checkWelcomeFiles">true</Set>
  </Get>

  <!-- Add context specific logger
 <Set name="handler">
   <New id="RequestLog" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler">
     <Set name="requestLog">
    <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
      <Set name="filename"><Property name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/jenkins-yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</Set>
      <Set name="filenameDateFormat">yyyy_MM_dd</Set>
      <Set name="append">true</Set>
      <Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>
    </New>
     </Set>
   </New>
 </Set>
 -->

</Configure>
```

Create the directory

```
mkdir -p /home/jetty/.jenkins
chown -R jetty:jetty /home/jetty/
```

The jenkins.xml file refers to the file [/etc/realm.properties](http://redutan.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/jetty9-jenkins-http-error-503-problem.html)

I created the /etc/realm.properties file and copied and pasted the following code:

```
#
# This file defines users passwords and roles for a HashUserRealm
#
# The format is
#  <username>: <password>[,<rolename> ...]
#
# Passwords may be clear text, obfuscated or checksummed.  The class
# org.eclipse.util.Password should be used to generate obfuscated
# passwords or password checksums
#
# If DIGEST Authentication is used, the password must be in a recoverable
# format, either plain text or OBF:.
#
jetty: MD5:164c88b302622e17050af52c89945d44,user
admin: CRYPT:adpexzg3FUZAk,server-administrator,content-administrator,admin,user
other: OBF:1xmk1w261u9r1w1c1xmq,user
plain: plain,user
user: password,user

# This entry is for digest auth.  The credential is a MD5 hash of username:realmname:password
digest: MD5:6e120743ad67abfbc385bc2bb754e297,user
```

Then the following commands performed

```
cp /etc/realm.properties /opt/jetty/etc    
chown -R jetty:jetty /opt/jetty/webapps
chown -R jetty:jetty /opt/jetty/etc
service jetty restart
```

I accessed the URL for the browser:
http://myserver:8080/jenkins

But displays the following message:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /jenkins/. Reason:

    Service Unavailable

Powered by Jetty://
```

I forgot to any permission? Why am I not able to access the jenkins? Where am I wrong?

Comment: What version of Jetty did you install?

Comment: Hello Joakim Erdfelt, I am distributing the jetty in version 8.1.9.v20130131

Comment: eek!  Jetty 7 and 8 are both EOL (End of Life) now.  Can you at least use any release from Jetty 9.2.x (or 9.3.x)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to deploy jenkins on the jetty correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254033/how-to-deploy-jenkins-on-the-jetty-correctly)